# "unresolved external symbol" error strange behavior

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker

When compiling a C++ project in Visual Studio 2008 I get the following linker error:

```
unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall OnlinePokerClient::isRegisteredWindow(struct HWND__ *)" (?isRegisteredWindow@OnlinePokerClient@@QAE_NPAUHWND__@@@Z) referenced in function "long __stdcall CBTProc(int,unsigned int,long)" (?CBTProc@@YGJHIJ@Z)
```

The code which generates the error is this:

```
if (!g_pClient->isRegisteredWindow(hWnd))
        g_pClient->registerWindow(hWnd, NULL);
```

Strange thing is, though, that I don't get a similar linker error for the registerWindow function which is defined in the same file as isRegsteredWindow(). In fact, if I comment the call to isRegisteredWindow() the projects compile just fine.

I think I might have messed up with some linker settings. I'm new to Visual Studio and I'm getting this error while trying to compile a solution composed of two projects: the first one is a DLL library while the other one is a GUI using MFC. The DLL is compiled and linked just fine, the GUI gets compiled but I get this error in the linking stage, even if those code lines are contained in the first (the DLL one) project.

Any help?

**ADD**

The isRegisteredWindow() function is declared in the OnlinePokerClient.h header and then defined in the corrisponding OnlinePokerClient.cpp file. This is the function itself:

```
bool OnlinePokerClient::isRegisteredWindow(HWND hWnd) {
    map<HWND, OnlineTableWindow*>::const_iterator iter = tables.find(hWnd);

    return iter != tables.end();
}
```

Of course the OnlinePokerClient.h file is included on top of the file generating the error.

Comment: Could you show the definition of isRegisteredWindow and its location within your code?

Comment: Well, the linker couldn't find isRegisteredWindow function. Where does this function reside? In DLL? If so, you should load it.

Comment: Edited the original question to add some details

Comment: And OnlinePokerClient.cpp is added to the project (and not excluded from build)?

Comment: Is a .lib generated for this dll ? And are you sure the code for this function is really compiled ? For example I once added a new item and choose .h instead of .cpp. Renaming the file doesn't mean VS will automatically include it in the compilation, so you may check if when your dll is compiled, it says this file is compiled within it.

Comment: @user786653: yes, OnlinePokerClient.cpp is correctly added to the project.

Comment: @Jonathan Merlet: according to the build log a .lib file is generated for the dll. The code is really compiled too. Strange thing is that I don't get a linker error for the other symbols defined in the same file

Comment: Hmm, you may have to add some [`__declspec(export)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a90k134d\(v=vs.80\).aspx)

Comment: Can you post the whole contents of the files? OnlinePokerClient.h/.cpp - feel free to exclude other functions, but leave the rest intact.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- If the function is defined as inline, try rebuilding entire solution.
- If function is implemented in CPP, ensure that `#if`/`#ifdef` are not omitting those code lines from compilation.
- If this class is in DLL, esnure the entire class is exported using `class __declspec(dllexport) TheClass` notation.
- Addition to above, ensure `#if` stuff is not excluding it from being compiled. Use Dependency Walker to check if function is actually exported from DLL.

Try adding some error in this function, and see if it actually gets compiled in first place.

Answer (score 0):

Since the  `isRegisteredWindow()` function is declared in the OnlinePokerClient.h header and then defined in the corrisponding OnlinePokerClient.cpp.

These are a few possibilities:

1. The chances are that the *object* file for the OnlinePokerClient.cpp file is not getting linked to your final executable.
2. may be your 'makefile' is not compiling the OnlinePokerClient.cpp itself.
3. Is OnlinePokerClient.cpp in other directory/folder that you are not including in your project settings?